# How to use different parent tag based on input?

Tags: angular

I have some content. Based on a condition it should be wrapped in a link or span:

```
<a *ngIf="condition">content</a>
<span *ngIf="!condition">content</span>
```

How can I do this without copy-pasting the content or putting it in a new component?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [interpolation](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#interpolation----):

```
<a *ngIf="condition">{{content}}</a>
<span *ngIf="!condition">{{content}}</span>
```

with the `content` property defined in the component class:

```
content = "My content";
```